# Retrieve gdb option values

Tags: gdb

Is there a way in gdb to retrieve (not print) the value of options like logging file, logging redirect, etc.? Why do they provide a set command but no get command?

Answer (score 1):

> Why do they provide a set command but no get command?

[The GDB manual covers this](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Logging-Output.html). The get command is usually called `show`, but sometimes `info`.

Comment: Well, show and info are both printing commands. I was looking for a value retrieval command that can be used programmatically in gdb scripts. I finally found a way, not in gdb syntax, but in the python API to gdb (gdb.parameter(<param-name>)). It works for non-prefix parameters (like "logging file"), but I still can't find a way to get it to work for prefix parameters (like "logging").